# python: How do I pass a list containing a string to an open file object using python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

locfile = ['fileone','filetwo','filetthree']

myfile = open('locfile','rU')

as you can see open file object expects a string with a file extension as well. 
I simply want to pass file names in as i process the list one file name at a time. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
locfile = ['fileone','filetwo','filetthree']
for x in locfile:
    file = openfile(x,'rU')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.